# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

controller.php

```
public function action_user() {
        $user_list = DB::select()->from('users')->execute();
//       print_r($user_list);
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user')
                                    ->bind('user_list',$user_list);
    }
```

when i print the `$user_list` in controller like this `print_r($user_list);` i am getting the values in array.In views i am trying to iterate using for loop and printing he variable.But i am getting this error "`ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object`".If i print the variable as `$user_list`,it is printing as array.

views.php

```
 <?php echo $user_list; ?> //printing array
    <?php
        foreach ($user_list as $user):
        echo $user->username;  //getting error here
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

Comment: This means the contents of your `$user_list` array are not objects.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Can you tell me how to solve this.

Comment: There is nothing more I can say to help you out with this, I told you exactly the problem you are having.

Comment: Use the [as_object](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/results#select-asobject-and-asassoc) method: `$user_list = DB::select()->from('zid_users')->as_object('User')->execute();` or alternatively you could use the [ORM](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#find_all) `$user_list = ORM::factory('User')->find_all();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [as_object](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/results#select-asobject-and-asassoc) method:

```
$user_list = DB::select()->from('zid_users')->as_object('User')->execute();
```

or the [ORM](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#find_all)

```
$user_list = ORM::factory('User')->find_all();
```